# Дождаться callback в сервисе

Tags: java, android, android-service

Подскажите как дождаться callback в intentservice

```
public class OverviewService extends IntentService
{
    private boolean isShow;
    private final String OVERVIEW_URL = "https://www.site.com/overview";
    private Intent intent;
    private RequestBody requestBody;

    public OverviewService()
    {
        super("OverviewService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        requestBody = new RequestBody(this);
        this.intent = intent;
        GsonPost <ApiResponse> request = new GsonPost <ApiResponse>(OVERVIEW_URL, requestBody.getOverview(), OverviewMassage.class, createMyReqSuccessListener(), createMyReqErrorListener(), this);
        VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
        isShow = intent.getBooleanExtra("bool", false);
    }

    private Response.Listener<ApiResponse> createMyReqSuccessListener()
    {
        return new Response.Listener<ApiResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(ApiResponse respone)
            {
                if (respone.getTypedAnswer() instanceof OverviewMassage)
                {
                    OverviewMassage om = respone.getTypedAnswer();
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(OverviewService.this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.balance)
                        .setContentTitle("Balance")
                        .setOngoing(isShow)
                        .setContentText(om.getBalance())
                        .setLights(Color.BLUE, 5000, 5000)
                        .setAutoCancel(isShow);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
                    WakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener()
    {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IntentService работает по умолчанию не в UI потоке. Засим вам не надо запускать задачу асинхронно.

Сейчас у вас сервис запускает задачу, видит, что в его потоке работа закончена и умирает, не дождавшись окончания задачи.

Значит вам надо запустить вашу задачу синхронно, без колбэков. Так сервис будет работать до её завершения и всё выполнит.